# Bootstrap theme for Material-UI

Tags: themes, material-ui, react-bootstrap

Is there a Material-UI theme that makes controls look like base Bootstrap theme? 
I know it's counter-intuitive, google search is full of the reverse examples.

Comment: Can you provide more details so I can help you a bit more, please? If you want a material-ui theme that looks just like bootstrap, why not just use bootstrap ?

Comment: It's about reusing the code of the other teams for an older project.

Comment: Doesn't tell me much about what you want exactly. Hopefully Matt's answer is what you were looking for because I can't do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible, [here](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/text-fields/#customized-inputs) you can see a Material-UI `TextField` component styled to look like Bootstrap, however I"m not aware of any ready-made themes that offer Bootstrap for Material-UI.